# model relation going both ways with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys

I have two models `reservations` and `reviews` I can go reservation.review and get a correct output in cases. However, when i go review.reservation im not getting the same respect i get the relation error `StatementInvalid`.

Reviews model:

```rails
 belongs_to :reservation, :foreign_key => :reservation_id, class_name: 'Reservation'
 belongs_to :reviser
 has_one :reviser
  has_one :reservation

  belongs_to :user
```

Reservation model:

```rails
has_one :review, :dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note about your `reviews` model. You have this line:

```
belongs_to :reservation, :foreign_key => :reservation_id, class_name: 'Reservation'
```

but since you're naming the foreign key `reservation_id`, which is what rails names the foreign key by default, you can simply get rid of that part and say:

```
belongs_to :reservation
```

Secondly, I'm not totally sure why you have `has_one :reservation` since you already have `belongs_to :reservation`. I would probably delete the `has_one :reservation` line unless you're absolutely sure it should be there.

So your new `reviews` model would look like this:

```
belongs_to :reservation
belongs_to :reviser
has_one :reviser

belongs_to :user
```

I would double check in your `schema.rb` file to ensure that you have the field `reservation_id` in your `reviews` table. That field must be present for the association to work properly.

Comment: Exactly it was that belongs_to ...haha i knew i should have just removed thank you!

Comment: No problem..glad I could help :)